# Showing Login Viewcontroler and dismissing it

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

So I have a simple app running flawlessly, now I want to add login screen, in other words when the app opens it check a boolean property (userIsAuthorisedBool) if yes continue running app normally, if no, switch user to Sign in screen (SigninViewController). The problem is checking and switching user to login screen. as well as dismissing it. here's my simple storyboard.

[image]

my attempt to solve the problem:

this code is in the main view controller

```
-(void) showLogin {
SigninViewController *signin = [[SigninViewController alloc] init];

self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;

[self presentViewController:signin animated:YES completion:^(void){}];

}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
if (!_userIsAuthorisedBool) {
    // switching to login screen because user is not authorised
    [self showLogin];

}


}
```

and why the heck I cannot write: `signin.delegate = self;` in `showLogin` function?

Thanks

Comment: You don't instantiate view controllers that you made in a storyboard with alloc init, you use instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:.

Comment: Or possibly even better is to use a segue.  Also I recommend against accessing iVars directly (_userIsAuthorisedBool) - use the property `self.userIsuthorisedBool` and the 'Bool' is implied by the 'is' prefix

Answer (score 0):

As i can see in your screenshot you have setup a Segue, give it a identifier "theIdentifier" and call it via:

[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"theIdentifier" sender:self];

You could show this segue as modal in case of a login.